# what is the meaning of "cost of option setting rt-wise" comment in MySQL Connector/J ClientPreparedStatement#executeBatchInternal?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

**Env: mysql-connector-java 8.0.19**

I have noticed that there is a comment says "**cost of option setting rt-wise**" in `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement#executeBatchInternal`  source code, when I do some batch operations using `PreparedStament`. Source code snippet from MySQL Connector/J as below:

```
if (!this.batchHasPlainStatements && this.rewriteBatchedStatements.getValue()) {
    if (((PreparedQuery<?>) this.query).getParseInfo().canRewriteAsMultiValueInsertAtSqlLevel()) {
        return executeBatchedInserts(batchTimeout);
    }

    if (!this.batchHasPlainStatements && this.query.getBatchedArgs() != null
            && this.query.getBatchedArgs().size() > 3 /* cost of option setting rt-wise */) {
        return executePreparedBatchAsMultiStatement(batchTimeout);
    }
}
```

so, my questions are:

1. what is the exact meaning of "cost of option setting rt-wise" phrase?
2. why MySQL Connector/J choose 3 as the bottom line to rewrite batched statements, why not 4 or other numbers?

thanks.

Comment: Without in-depth knowledge of the implementation, this isn't really possible to answer here, making it an opinion-based answer, and thus off-topic. Ask MySQL/Oracle the question directly. BTW, if I had to guess, the 'rt' on 'rt-wise' stands for 'roundtrip', though I'm not sure how that will help you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Indeed. I am ready to ask MySQL about the question. In case of someone just know the specific details of this question, keeping the question be open is still necessary in my opinion. If I got some certain answers from somewhere, I will answer it here. Thanks again.